# Groovy Compilation Error: unexpected token

Tags: groovy

```
assert 'c' ==~ (?i:[^c].*)
```

the groovy console output:

```
groovy> assert 'c' ==~ (?i:[^c-d].*); 
                         ^
```

1 compilation error:
unexpected token: ? at line: 1, column: 17

Why am i getting an unexptected token here?

Comment: I've added a "^" to highlight column 17. Can you check that I've put it in the right place? Just in case there's a cut'n'paste error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an escape before the paren... And you don't need the colon after the case-insensitive modifier. (?i) is fine. However, know that your assertion will always be 'falsey' as case insensitive c will never match for the negated range [^c-d].

```
assert 'c' ==~ /(?i)([^c-d].*)/
```

Comment: Isn't that a slashy quote, rather than an escape?

Comment: Not sure... might be... my groovy is a bit ... iffy.

Comment: Thank you Eddie B that worked.  The funny this is that i have have this work like this before assert 'c' ==~ (?i[^c].*)

Comment: This works as well /(?i:[^c].*)/ I guess the slashes need to be added when this is ran in the groovy console

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the regex you're trying to build is "any string that starts with any character not in the range C to D (case insensitive)", then your ":" should be ")(":

```
(?i)([^c-d].*)
```

`(?i)` is the match flag for "case insensitive".

Comment: I wonder if the OP knows that this RE is 'falsey' ... 'C' doesn't ever match (?i)[^c-d]

Comment: doing an assert of this will fail

Comment: I know, but it's what you wanted. There's no requirement in the question that it should pass.